# correct way to include javascript for a particular page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It seems that the rails 3 way is to include all the javascript globally to the application.  Am I correct on this?

What is the reasoning?

If I am not correct, what is the standard way to include page specific javascript?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Rails 3 will include **application.js** which contains `//= require_tree` making it depend on on all other JS files in **/app/assets/javascripts**.

You can remove `//= require_tree` in **application.js** and `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in **application.html.erb** and include controller-specific JS by adding the following:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller].split("/")[0])
```

Then, make JS files (**app/assets/javascripts/CONTROLLER-NAME.js**) for each controller containing:

1. `//= require application`
2. Your controller-specific JS

These will then depend on **application.js** but can have their own JS as well.

The `.split` method allows controllers like Devise to use their first name before the / as the name for the .js file so you only have to create **devise.js** instead of **devise/sessions.js** and others.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `content_for` tag to add page specific content to the head of the page.

In your

**application.html.erb** (your layout file) under your javascript includes you add a line that says

`<%= content_for :js_include %>`

then in any page you want to include a page specific javascript you just do

```
<% content_for :js_include do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "some_javascript_file" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if you have to inlcude the = sign on the javascript_include_tag (just make sure you put it as it is on the `application.html.erb` file but that's pretty much the gist of it. Using content_for tags

**EDIT**

Some helpful links

[Railscasts Episode Layouts and Content For](http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for)

[Rails API content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways:

```
<%= javascript_tag "...javascript..." %>
* Generates <script type="text/javascript">...javascript...</script>
```

Or

```
<% content_for :script do %>
   ...javascript...
<% end %>
* This approach includes script into <%= yield :script %> defined in the template anywhere, for example inside the <head> dom:
<head>
  ...
  <% if content_for?(:script) %>
    <%= javascript_tag yield(:script) %>
  <% end %>

</head>
```

Or many many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

To include specific javascript files into specific view pages only, you need to go with the following procedure.

```
i) In the assets folder create a separate folder eg. 'separate_view' , and inside put your specific js, and css files.

ii) In the application lay out write like following for 'separate_view'.
  <%= yield :separate_view %>

iii) In your target template write the following for 'separate_view'.
  <% content_for (:separate_view) do %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "xxx.js" %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "xxx.css" %>
  <%end%>
```

The above will go fine with your specific view files.